# R Tree With n Branches

Tags: r, recursion, tree, logic

How can I generate a tree with n nodes, each of which have m number of children, with the condition that each child node is obtained by fun(parent)?

I've gleaned some logic from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382570/tree-with-multiple-child-nodes-and-next-node), but I am stuck on how to generate up to n names, and also how to generate the functions for assigning newly generated children to their parents recursively. (insert utopian joke here)

-Edit-

I've attempted using TheTime's solution below, and this certainly answered this question. However, I didn't ask the question I intended. Because this question has a good answer that could be useful in certain circumstances, I've posted a new question that asks what I really meant [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772031/k-nary-trees-in-r-with-variable-number-of-leaves-per-branch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is one way, alternatively you could use a 'stack' data structure.  I'm not sure what kind of function you are thinking of using or what sort of values you plan on storing, so here is simply a function that creates a child node's name using its parent's name as well.

```
## Function to apply to nodes to create children
nodeNamer <- function() {
    i <- 0
    function(node) sprintf("%s -> %g", node$name, (i <<- i+1))
}

make_tree <- function(depth, m, fn) {
    root <- Node$new('root')

    ## Some helper function to recurse
    f <- function(node, depth) {
        if (depth <= 0) return( root )
        for (i in seq.int(m)) {
            val <- fn(node)  # apply some function to parent node
            child <- node$AddChild(val)
            Recall(child, depth-1)  # recurse, Recall refers to 'f'
        }
    }
    f(root, depth)
    return( root )
}

## Make a tree with depth of '2' and 3 branches from each node
## Note that the way I defined the naming function, you must call it 
## in order to reset the the counter to 0
res <- make_tree(2, 3, nodeNamer())

res
#                  levelName
# 1  root                   
# 2   ¦--root -> 1          
# 3   ¦   ¦--root -> 1 -> 2 
# 4   ¦   ¦--root -> 1 -> 3 
# 5   ¦   °--root -> 1 -> 4 
# 6   ¦--root -> 5          
# 7   ¦   ¦--root -> 5 -> 6 
# 8   ¦   ¦--root -> 5 -> 7 
# 9   ¦   °--root -> 5 -> 8 
# 10  °--root -> 9          
# 11      ¦--root -> 9 -> 10
# 12      ¦--root -> 9 -> 11
# 13      °--root -> 9 -> 12
```

Comment: You've saved my bacon recently - I appreciate your help. This code does exactly what I asked for, however, it's not what I wanted! I did a poor job stating in my question that the number of children will actually vary per node. I've tried reconstructing the script you wrote - and I'm hitting a few snags. I really want to start with a parent value, say x<- c(1,2,3,4), apply function to this node, which will generate the child nodes, name the child nodes, and then recursively apply the function to each child node until no new nodes are generated.

Comment: True story - that's what I get for being too general (and too tired). Here's the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772031/k-nary-trees-in-r-with-variable-number-of-leaves-per-branch. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm a little newer to the etiquette of these forums, but I'm picking it up (much like R programming). The new post is more descriptive and has good examples in both visual and code format.