# Building N-ary tree in R

Tags: r, tree

How can I build an N-ary tree in R for a given number of branches and depth, for example a binary tree of depth 3?

EDIT: separate source question to question and answer.

Comment: There is the `make_tree` function from the `igraph` package

Comment: @user20650 i think it something another what i need. I need a data structure which can store tree data wihtout direction. igraph is complex soulution of my task, i prefer data.tree which is more simple for me. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: For those voting to close - I think the question provides enough information to be answered, and  they do provide an answer which may  be useful to other users

Comment: Why my question is off-topic? Is this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768841/r-tree-with-n-branches off-topic too?

Comment: Hi V. Gai - I think some of the votes to close were received before you had edited your original question, to split it into a clearly defined Q and separate A. Also some people do *always expect to see some code / effort* in the question - here it is applied a bit over-zealously in my opinion given that you have provided answer. However, that said, your question has received four votes to reopen, and just needs one more, so should get there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to present the solution, which i used to build a tree data structure with **leafAmn** branching factor. To store data in the tree the field **myData** is used. Also function to print the content of the tree is defined. Also it exists a recursive solution of this task: [R Tree With n Branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768841/r-tree-with-n-branches).

```
# function to build N-ary tree
makeTree <- function(depth, leafAmn)  
{
## leafAmn - branching factor
## depth   - depth of tree
library(data.tree)

myTree <- Node$new("root", myData = c(-1)) # root node
for (i in 1:depth) # loop by tree depth
{
    if (i == 1)
    # create a set of nodes with depth 1
    {
        chldArr1 <- matrix("", 1, leafAmn)
        for (j in 1:leafAmn)
        {
            # create children nodes
            myTree$AddChild(j, myData = c())
            # save links to children nodes to array 'chldArr1'
            # this array is used to generate tree without using recursion
            chldArr1[j] <- sprintf("myTree$children[[%d]]$", j)
        }
    }
    else
    # add childs at level 'i' to nodes at level 'i-1' using 
    # method AddChild
    {
        chldArr2 <- matrix("", 1, (leafAmn ^ i))
        k <- 1
        for (j in 1:(leafAmn ^ (i - 1)))
        {
            for (m in 1:leafAmn)
            {
                # create string which contains a command to execute
                # this command is used to add child to nodes at previous level
                commStr <- paste(chldArr1[j], sprintf("AddChild(%d, myData = c())", m), sep = "")
                eval(parse(text = commStr))
                print(commStr)
                # save command to array 'chldArr2'
                chldArr2[k] <- paste(chldArr1[j], sprintf("children[[%d]]$", m), sep = "")
                k <- k + 1
            }
        }
        chldArr1 <- chldArr2
    }
}

## Make a tree with depth of '3' and 2 branches from each node
myTree <- makeTree(3, 2)
print(myTree, "myData")

>     myTree <- makeTree(3, 2)
[1] "myTree$children[[1]]$AddChild(1, myData = c())"
[1] "myTree$children[[1]]$AddChild(2, myData = c())"
[1] "myTree$children[[2]]$AddChild(1, myData = c())"
[1] "myTree$children[[2]]$AddChild(2, myData = c())"
[1] "myTree$children[[1]]$children[[1]]$AddChild(1, myData = c())"
[1] "myTree$children[[1]]$children[[1]]$AddChild(2, myData = c())"
[1] "myTree$children[[1]]$children[[2]]$AddChild(1, myData = c())"
[1] "myTree$children[[1]]$children[[2]]$AddChild(2, myData = c())"
[1] "myTree$children[[2]]$children[[1]]$AddChild(1, myData = c())"
[1] "myTree$children[[2]]$children[[1]]$AddChild(2, myData = c())"
[1] "myTree$children[[2]]$children[[2]]$AddChild(1, myData = c())"
[1] "myTree$children[[2]]$children[[2]]$AddChild(2, myData = c())"
>     print(myTree, "myData")
       levelName myData
1  root              -1
2   ¦--1             NA
3   ¦   ¦--1         NA
4   ¦   ¦   ¦--1     NA
5   ¦   ¦   °--2     NA
6   ¦   °--2         NA
7   ¦       ¦--1     NA
8   ¦       °--2     NA
9   °--2             NA
10      ¦--1         NA
11      ¦   ¦--1     NA
12      ¦   °--2     NA
13      °--2         NA
14          ¦--1     NA
15          °--2     NA
```

Comment: Just fyi, the package already does this. Check out e.g. CreateRegularTree(3,2)

Answer (score 1):

Well, long time ago, when Q-BASIC didn't have any pointer option, there was a way to express binary tree without pointer. It's simple mathematical trick. When you assign 1 to root, it has two children - 2,3. "2" has two children "4, 5," which can be represented as "index*2" and "index*2+1" As such, we can represent binary tree with just array. Here's my code.

```
#Binomial option pricing (2)
#We can expand the tree to more than 3rd depth.
#U = exp(volatility)
#D = exp(-volatility)
#p = 0.5 (We have the equal chance of making or losing money)
#Risk free rate = 0.02 => exp(0.02)
#For those who are not familiar with data structure, I deliberately used just array.
#I'll make a new code for those who are familiar with tree data structure

library(igraph)

#Define the variable
depth<-3 #How many steps (tree depth) do you want to make
rate <-0.02 #Risk Free rate
volatility <- 0.35
exercise_price <- 35
stock_price <- 47.5
upside_probability<-(exp(rate)-exp(-volatility))/(exp(volatility)-exp(-volatility))
rate <- exp(rate)

total_node<-2^depth-1 #Total number of node
G <- graph.tree(n=total_node, children=2) #I'll make a graph whose nodes are 7, and each node has two children
stock_tree <- (1:total_node)

stock_tree[1]<-stock_price
tree_traverse <- 2^(depth-1) -1

for(i in 1:tree_traverse) {
    #We are going to use mathematical trick to represent tree.
    stock_tree[i*2] <- stock_tree[i] * exp(volatility)
    stock_tree[i*2 + 1] <- stock_tree[i] * exp(-volatility)
}

V(G)$name <- round(stock_tree) #Name of the tree
lay <- layout.reingold.tilford(G) #It's tree. You can try other shape with other layout options
plot(G, layout=lay, vertex.size=15, edge.arrow.size=0.1) #Draw the tree.

#As opposed to the stock price, the option pricing starts out with end nodes (bottom nodes)
#I already explained the logic. Just follow it from one by one.
option_price<-(1:total_node)
bottom_node<-tree_traverse + 1

#In order to value the option, we need to calculate bottom line first.
for(i in bottom_node:total_node) {
  after_option <- stock_tree[i] - exercise_price

  if( after_option >0 ) {
    option_price[i] <- after_option
  } else {
    option_price[i] <- 0
  }
}

#Discount it back to current time while considering the probabilty of up and down
for(i in tree_traverse:1) {
    option_price[i]<-upside_probability*option_price[i*2]
    option_price[i]<-option_price[i]+(1-upside_probability)*option_price[i*2+1]
    option_price[i]<-option_price[i]/rate
}

V(G)$name <- round(option_price)
plot(G, layout=lay, vertex.size=15, edge.arrow.size=0.1)
```