# How to create csv file of multiple generations of directories ie layers of subdirectories

Tags: r, list, csv, directory, subdirectory

I have a large directory with many layers/generations of directories within, lets say 5 layers. I am trying to count the occurrence/presence of the final generation of subdirectories (not the files within the final subdirectory).

eg parent directory (gen1) and all subdirectories within gen1 (gen2) and all subdirectories within gen2 (gen3) and all subdirectories within gen3 (gen4) and all subdirectories within gen4 (gen5)

To do this I would like to create a .csv with the names of all 5 generations of directories, so each row in the csv will show a final subdirectory name (gen5) and all the above parent directories (gen4, 3, 2, 1), separated by columns. I can then count directory occurrences at different levels by filtering by directory name.

There is a different amount of subdirectories at each level. eg gen2 has 4 folders -> Folder1 = 8 subdirectories, Folder2 = 12 subdirectories, Folder3 = 6 subdirectories, Folder4 15 subdirectories and so on...

I'm using R on windows and have tried applying the list.dirs() and the list.files() but can't get past manually listing each subdirectory individually, and can't figure out how to exclude the files - this makes my R crash as the files are too large. Surely I can spit out a csv file showing multiple generations of just directories by name? Struggling to find a code that excludes the files and only spits out the directories.

here's what I'm hoping the output will look like:

[image: example output table]

Comment: Have you tried using the args of `list.files()`? There you can access all subdirectories

Comment: I specifically don't want to list the files in the final subdirectories as there are way too many in each and they are huge files, it crashes R whenever I use this list.dirs(path = ".", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)

Comment: Are you Windows, linux, or mac?

Comment: Can [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768841/r-tree-with-n-branches)  help?

Comment: @chris on windows

Comment: @RuiBarradas I'm pretty new to R, that post didn't make much sense to me unfortunately.

Comment: I'm struggling to play around with the code, as everything I'm trying ends up loading all the files in the final folder layer which keeps crashing R or would needs days of loading time... so I abort it.

Comment: Do you need the csv file with the sub-directories or only the final count?

Answer (score 1):

The following function goes down the directory tree recursively and adds 1 each time it finds a leaf. Optionally, it will save the leaves names in a file.

```
count_dirs <- function(path = ".", savefile = FALSE, filename) {
  f <- function(path) {
    if(dir.exists(paths = path)) {
      dir_vec <- list.dirs(path = path, full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE)
      if(length(dir_vec) == 1L) {
        e$n <- e$n + 1L
        if(savefile) {
          df1 <- data.frame(directory = dir_vec)
          write.table(
            df1, e$outfile, 
            quote = FALSE, 
            row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE,
            append = TRUE
          )
        }
      } else {
        for(d in dir_vec)  Recall(path = d)
      }
    }
  }
  e <- new.env()
  e$n <- 0L
  if(savefile) {
    e$outfile <- filename
    df1 <- data.frame(directory = character(0))
    write.table(df1, e$outfile, quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
  }
  path <- normalizePath(path = path)
  if(.Platform$OS.type == "windows") {
    path <- chartr("\\", "/", path)
  }
  f(path = path)
  e$n
}

# sample usage    
tmpfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".dat")
count_dirs(savefile = TRUE, filename = tmpfile)
# [1] 79

# tidy up
#unlink(tmpfile)
```

Comment: thanks for your help.
Unfortunately I couldnt get that code to run, and without really understanding the code it would take me too long to resolve all the errors. 
Is a leaf a subdirectory? 

Would there be a way for me to create a csv with all the 5th generation directories (final folder that stores all the large files) and then just include the parent directories as a path?

Comment: @guppieregina In the directory tree, a leaf is a terminal node, the last sub-directory (5th generation, in  your directory structure). What didn't run? Can you edit the question with the errors or output you got?

Comment: @guppieregina, on my user dir, `count_dirs('~/', savefile = TRUE, 'my_folders.txt')
[1] 16737`, memory stable...`readLines('./my_folders.txt')[8000]
[1] "/home/chris/llvm-project/build/examples/BrainF/CMakeFiles"`, only dirs, no files. Should do what you want, but absent 'Error:` no way to know your experience.